# Array elements disappearing / not loading

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop, collections

I have no idea what is going on here and it's a little bizzare.

I'm adapting a VBA macro into a VB.net project, and I'm experiencing what I would describe as some extreemly unusual behavior of a method I'm using to pass data around in VB.net.  Here's the set up...

I have, for indexing reasons, a collection that consists of all open orders:

```
Public allOpenOrders As New Collection
```

Within this collection, I store other collections, indexed by account number, that each contain information about each open order in an array that is three elements long.  Here is how I'm populating it:

```
openOrderData(0) = some information
openOrderData(1) = some information
openOrderData(2) = some information
SyncLock allOpenOrders
    If allOpenOrders.Contains(accountNumber) Then
        'Already in the collection...
        accountOpenOrders = allOpenOrders(accountNumber)
        accountOpenOrders.Add(openOrderData)
    Else
        'Not already in collection
        accountOpenOrders = New Collection
        accountOpenOrders.Add(openOrderData)
        allOpenOrders.Add(accountOpenOrders, AccountNumber)
    End If
End SyncLock
```

Here's the thing, if I place a stop after end synclock and check the collection, I can clearly see that the array with all data is there, plain as day.  However, when I move on in my code (this is occuring in another thread after the preceeding code has executed) to retrieve it and write it to a workbook...

```
If allOpenOrders.Contains(accountNumber) Then
    accountOpenOrders = allOpenOrders(accountNumber)
    For each openOrderArray In accountOpenOrders
        OutputSheet.Cells(1, 1).value = accountNumber
        For counter = 0 to 2
            OutputSheet.Cells(1, counter + 2).value = openOrderArray(counter)
        Next counter
    Next openOrderArray
End If
```

I get the first element of the array in column B, but C and D are blank.  Even more puzzling, if I put a stop right after the allOpenOrders.Contains line I can look at the collection and the last two elements of the array are now blank.  Most puzzling of all, they aren't just blank, they are blanks, a number of blanks equal in length to the original field I recorded in that element of the array?!

Any ideas are appreciated.  I can tell you I'm using the same type of method to load other data in this workbook with no problems.  These are also the only instances in which the allOpenOrders collection is touched... I'm so confused by these results.

Comment: Is allOpenOrders defined in a class that can be instantiated more than once? If it is, I would guess that you are dealing with different instances of allOpenOrders. You can either move the declaration of allOpenOrders to a Module or a Shared class to prevent this issue.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman allOpenOrders was declared public for the entire class containing this code.  As it turns out, I was reusing the opeOrderData array after it had been added to the collection, and that is how my data was being overwritten.